# c# String to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have following string stored in datatable's column with varchar or string datatype
"4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM"

Now i want to convert this string to datetime

Or 
let me make more clear
I just want to extract time part from this string "4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM"
and store it in Database.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For

Comment: Have you check out the documentation in MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx

Comment: You want to store it back as a string, or as a different type than string?

Comment: Why store a date as a string in the database?

Answer (score 4):

```
 // String to DateTime
 String MyString;
 MyString = "4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM";

 DateTime MyDateTime;
 MyDateTime = new DateTime();
 MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                                  null);
```

this should work for you.

Comment: +1 becuase this answer does not make UASA based assumptions about the local of the database or the code accessing it.

Comment: Almost right - you really should have `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` as the month may be two digits.

Comment: +1 for giving the format because many times date parsing is a pain in the ass. If we know the format prior, it's better to give it. In the writing part also this has to be take care.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is a fairly simple operation you can use `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dbString)` and then use `date.ToString("hh:mm tt")` To get just the time and AM/PM. in the form "09:00 PM"

'hh' stands for the hours 01 to 12,

'mm' stands for the minutes 00 to 59,

'tt' stands for AM/PM

You could also use `date.ToString("h:mm tt")` to get the form "9:00 PM".

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime yourDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    string myDateTimeString = "4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM";
    DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeString);
    string myTimeString = myDateTime.Date.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Time part of string in SQL :

```
select  DATEPART(HOUR , cast('4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM' as datetime) ) as hr
      , DATEPART(MINUTE , cast('4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM' as datetime) ) as minute
      , DATEPART(SECOND , cast('4/29/2013 9:00:00 PM' as datetime) ) as sec
```

Comment: @lelyor  - Actually he did.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this ext:

```
public static class Ext
{

    public static string AsLocaleDateString(this DateTime dt)
    {
        var format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;

        return dt.ToString(format.ShortDatePattern);
    }

    public static DateTime? AsLocaleDate(this string str)
    {
        if (str.IsNullEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }
        var format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;

        return DateTime.ParseExact(str, format.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }

}
```